# Javascript on Chrome - How to get correct heading values from the deviceorientationabsolute event?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, augmented-reality

I am trying to retrieve **absolute** heading values in `Google Chrome` on `Android` using `javascript` for a web app which uses geo location.

I am listening to the new `deviceorientationabsolute` event:

```
if ('ondeviceorientationabsolute' in window) {
   window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", ondeviceorientationabsolute, true);
} 
else if ('ondeviceorientation' in window) {
   window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", ondeviceorientation, true);
}
```

The corresponding method gets called successfully:

```
if (event.absolute  === true) {
     if (event.alpha === null) {
        return;
     }

     console.log('absolute: ' + event.absolute)     // true
     console.log('alpha: ' + event.alpha)           // 0.00 (at the start)
}
```

But this gives me the current relative alpha value instead of the absolute one, even though `event.absolute` resolves to `true`.
This means, it behaves exactly like the default `deviceorientation` event.

Any ideas why this does not behave as expected?

Comment: same issue even today, was you able to fix?